Equals method never called by LINQ expression
My data class:
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using static iText.StyledXmlParser.Jsoup.Select.Evaluator;

namespace WebApi.Entities
{
    public class AgentTask : IEquatable<AgentTask>, IComparable<AgentTask>
    {
        [DefaultValue("1")]
        [Key]
        public int FunctionId { get; set; }
        public string PreferredTime { get; set; }
        public string UserFunction { get; set; }
        public string Group { get; set; }
        public Boolean IsGroup { get; set; } = false;

        public int CompareTo(AgentTask other)
        {
            if (UserFunction.CompareTo(other) != 0)
            {
                return UserFunction.CompareTo(other);
            }
            else
            {
                return Group.CompareTo(other);
            }
        }

        public override bool Equals(object obj)
        {
            var newObj = obj as AgentTask;

            if (null != newObj)
            {
                return Equals(newObj);
            }
            else
            {
                return base.Equals(obj);
            }
        }

        public bool Equals(AgentTask other)
        {
            if (null != other)
            {
                return this.UserFunction == other.UserFunction
                    //&& this.PreferredTime == newObj.PreferredTime
                    && this.Group == other.Group
                    && this.GetHashCode() == other.GetHashCode();
            }
            else
            {
                return base.Equals(other);
            }
        }

        public override int GetHashCode()
        {
            int hash = 19;
            unchecked
            { // allow "wrap around" in the int
                hash = hash * 31 + this.UserFunction.GetHashCode();
                //hash = hash * 31 + this.PreferredTime.GetHashCode(); // assuming integer
                hash = hash * 31 + this.Group.GetHashCode();
            }
            return hash;
        }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return base.ToString();
        }
    }
}

I have a class that contains a collection of AgentTask called Account:
public class Account : IdentityUser
    {
        ...
        public List<AgentTask> UserFunctions { get; set; }
    }

I also have a LINQ query that I want to return an array of accounts from whose UserFunctions are equal to a pre-defined AgentTask task. My query:
var accounts = _context.Accounts.Include(x => x.UserFunctions)
                        .Where((a) => a.UserFunctions.Any((t) => t.Equals(task))).ToArray();

accounts variable is always of 0 length array. Why?
Console output:
SELECT "a"."Id", "a"."AcceptTerms", "a"."AccessFailedCount", "a"."ConcurrencyStamp", "a"."Created", "a"."DOB", "a"."Email", "a"."EmailConfirmed", "a"."FirstName", "a"."LastName", "a"."LockoutEnabled", "a"."LockoutEnd", "a"."NormalizedEmail", "a"."NormalizedUserName", "a"."NotifyThreeDaysBefore", "a"."NotifyWeekBefore", "a"."PasswordHash", "a"."PasswordReset", "a"."PhoneNumber", "a"."PhoneNumberConfirmed", "a"."ResetToken", "a"."ResetTokenExpires", "a"."Role", "a"."SecurityStamp", "a"."Title", "a"."TwoFactorEnabled", "a"."Updated", "a"."UserName", "a"."VerificationToken", "a"."Verified", "u0"."FunctionId", "u0"."AccountId", "u0"."Group", "u0"."IsGroup", "u0"."PreferredTime", "u0"."UserFunction"
FROM "AspNetUsers" AS "a"
LEFT JOIN "UserFunctions" AS "u0" ON "a"."Id" = "u0"."AccountId"
WHERE EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM "UserFunctions" AS "u"
    WHERE "a"."Id" = "u"."AccountId" AND "u"."FunctionId" = @__entity_equality_task_0_FunctionId)
ORDER BY "a"."Id"


Then its presumably executed on the db server and whatever you implemented in the class for comparision/equality is irrelevant as its not known in the db. Either be explicit in the statement shown here or compare, implement a comparison method in the database and surface it to your context or pull all data locally to do the comparision locally only then you actually use Linq and your IEquatable/IComparable implementations might be used.

If I use var accounts = (_context.Accounts.Include(x => x.UserFunctions))                         .Where(a => a.UserFunctions.Any(t => t.UserFunction.Equals(task.UserFunction) && t.Group.Equals(task.Group))).ToArray(); it works fine

I think it would be simpler to start from UserFunctions, find some relevant ones and travel along to the single Account, rather than start from Account and return only those where one of their related UserFunctions is x. It's always simpler to travel from the many end to the one end because the many-end entity has a singular property of the parent

Equals is automatically translated by EF Core to a normal = on the SQL side. It cannot execute client code on the server.
Because you are comparing two entities, you end up with a primary key comparison, which is not what you want.
Instead, do the comparison directly in the LINQ expression
var accounts = _context.Accounts
    .Include(x => x.UserFunctions)
    .Where(a => a.UserFunctions.Any(
        t => t.UserFunction == task.UserFunction
             && t.Group == task.Group
        )
    ).ToArray();


Is this a statement I should be using?

isn't this question a duplicate?

Possibly, although the usage of Equals is confusing things as any other function would have thrown an InvalidOperationException making it more obvious what was happening.
